# Hiding only subcategories in Woocommerce

Tags: css, woocommerce

I am working on a website, which is a kind of e-commerce website, I use woo-commerce for the e-commerce part of thing.

My problem is the next: I have a lot of categories and sub categories and I want to hide the thumbnail of all my subcategories, but still display the images of the product and the categories.

To make things more simple, lets consider, product landing page with X, Y, Z as 3 categories.

The three categories have thumbnails, and after clicking in the category X we get a landing page with X1, X2, X3,.. Xn sub-categories with thumbnails.

Finally, if I click in the sub-category X1, I get product X11, X12, X13...X1n (this is the page before the product landing page)

In this situation I want to only display thumbnail/ for category X, and product X11, X12..... AND HIDE thumbnails for subcategory pages X1, X2, X3.... etc

The same thing should work for category Y, Z.

I tried different custom CSS from forum pages but nothing was precise to what I wanted, I also tried searching in the menus but there is nothing tailored to what I want.

EDIT:

Thanks everyone for your replies, It seemed clear in my head when I posted my question, but it isn't I'm sorry I should have upload some photos to explain better what was on my mind, so here I am.

[image]

Refer to the product page where you can see the first categories with thumbnails, these doesn't bother me at all and I don't want to change something at all.

After clicking in the category marked by the red box, I'm sent to the next page, with the link below.

[image]

Where I want to hide the thumbnails which are marked by a blue rectangle

[image]

This is the product page, where I don't need to change anything.

PS: I can't give the website link because it is still under construction, hidden from the search engine.

Comment: You can receive better help if you can show screenshots and the code that you are working with. If you can reproduce a demo, people can debug and find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

how much I understand is you want the products to be displayed once clicked on parent category instead of showing subcategories. So basically you want to show products on category page.

If this is the case you can select show products in category display settings under appearance > customize > woocommerce

[image]